# CGAL: How to create a sphere mesh?

Tags: cgal

How can I build a sphere mesh by cgal?
I want to use SurfaceMesh data structure to store a sphere

I tried to use the example:
[Surface_mesher_2mesh_an_implicit_function_8cpp-example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesher/Surface_mesher_2mesh_an_implicit_function_8cpp-example.html)
But the sphere is irregular in shape.
[irregular_sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXB3Z.png)
And I want to generate a sphere like this, what should I do?
[regular_sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZZhI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this blog post](https://danielsieger.com/blog/2021/03/27/generating-spheres.html) by Daniel Sieger.
Note that CGAL offers the subdivision functions, as well as the [function to construct an isocahedron](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLHelperFct.html#gaf6f8f1e7f78646f801a7a9627b0470ef) So you have to assemble this and add the projection to the sphere.

Answer (score 1):

The iterated Loop subdivision of an icosahedron produces a sphere (the icosphere).

```cpp
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/Subdivision_method_3/subdivision_methods_3.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef K::Point_3                                          Point3;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Point3>                          Mesh3;

Mesh3 icosphere(Point3 center, double radius, unsigned int iterations) {
  Mesh3 mesh;
  CGAL::make_icosahedron<Mesh3, Point3>(mesh, center, radius);
  CGAL::Subdivision_method_3::Loop_subdivision(
    mesh, CGAL::parameters::number_of_iterations(iterations)
  );
  return mesh;
}
```